# How to get class object for C[] given class object for C

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I was given a `java.lang.Class` object which refers to `C.class`. What is the most elegant/efficient way to get a `java.lang.Class` which refers to `C[].class`?

I can do it with `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, 0).getClass()` but this does not look very nice. Any other options?

Comment: Well, there's `Class.forName("[L" + class.getName() + ";")`. I wouldn't feel proud of myself for writing that, though.

Comment: @TomAnderson Could you please explain what is `[L`?

Comment: @iccthedral, Java has special notation which is used when printing the names of "array" classes -- that's the "[L" which you see here. (Sometimes you will see this in your IDE's debugger when looking at the values and classes of variables.) I think there may be also be special notation for certain other "special" types of classes, but I can't recall clearly right now.

Comment: @iccthedral see the JavaDoc on [Class.getName()](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName\(\))

Comment: @TomAnderson: that approach doesn't work for primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever way you do this, the code is not going to look very nice. By its very nature, Java code which uses reflection tends to be rather verbose. The best you can do is to put this code inside a utility method, so the ugliness and verbosity will be localized to that one method and kept out of the rest of your code.